# iOS 7 memory issues

Tags: memory-management, memory-leaks, ios7

I was recently trying to make my iOS 6 compatible app work with iOS 7 (noted still in beta). So i had my boss install iOS 7 on his iPhone 4S. We noticed that camera picker was slow and not responsive, and when we take a picture everything freezes. When i run the profile with memory allocations i notice that we have a really high memory usage : 160 MB. and btw we received a loot of memory warnings. So i tried running on the iPhone that still has ios6 and the maximum memory spike was 16 MB. Has anyone encountered this problem? Thank you

Comment: Quite a sad thing. For my app I got it as 1.55MB in iOS6 and 8.21MB in iOS7 for the same scenario. My profiler screenshots are here: http://plainoldstan.blogspot.cz/2013/09/ios-7-vs-ios-6-memory-consumption-omg.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do observe different Memory numbers on iOS 6 & iOS 7.
I have an app that makes use of openGL (a 3D viewer), and of AVFoundation (my own camera implementation, with `AVCaptureDevice`...)

I ran the app on iPhone 4S with iOS 6, and on iPhone 4 with iOS 7, my observations so far :

- Allocations, Dirty & resident VM sizes reported by Instruments seem higher on iOS 7 than iOS 6 (50% to 100% higher)

BUT

- I get much less Memory warning with iOS 7 (although I probably would have to repeat these tests to get more reliable results)

Comment: So, these are the 2 profile pictures of the same app on 2 different phones: iOS 7: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/146080740/Screenshots/1s.png and on iOS 6 http://dl.dropbox.com/u/146080740/Screenshots/1t.png

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 7, apple introduce more restriction on memory allocation for single instance. If the single thread uses more memory it should crash.

This is not only related to native application but also related to hybrid app.

Ex: Google Maps getting crashed only in iOS 7, if it uses more memory. You can able to get more information in the below link.

[Crashes in iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18759401/google-map-crashes-in-ios7)