# PhoneGap Build iOS app crashes on iOS 7

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, cordova, crash

I have an iOS app built with Phonegap Build 2.9 using the plugins supported by PhoneGap Build. it has been working flawlessly in the last few months with iOS 6.1.x.

Now with iOS 7, my app crashes constantly after few minutes of usage with a "low virtual memory" error. I have not changed a single line of code in my app so I'm seeking for advice to migrate my PhoneGap Build app to iOS 7.

I tried to rebuild my own iOS app using PhoneGap libraries in Xcode.  Using Xcode 5's memory allocation and memory leaks detection tools, I manage to track the root cause of the memory issues. It seems that every time I initiate a call to a PhoneGap plugin (Facebook Connect, SocialMessage, etc.), the memory usage jumps couple MBytes. The constant jump in memory usage eventually causes my iOS app to crash or being minimized by iOS itself.

Has anyone out there experience the similar problem? Has anyone in the PhoneGap Build team test existing Phonegap 2.9 & 3.0 libraries, PhoneGap plugins and sample apps for virtual memory issues with iOS 7? What is the recommendation for migrating existing PhoneGap Build apps to iOS 7?

Comment: It is due to memory issue in ios7. [Crash in ios7][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18759401/google-map-crashes-in-ios7/18944702#18944702