# iOS 7 recording crashing due to memory leak issue

Tags: cordova, ios7, cordova-3

I have build an app using phonegap 3.1 for iOS. It's working fine in iOS 6 but it was crashing in iOS 7 due to memory leak issue. it's happening when i start recording the red bar appearing in top of the window. Also, apps is getting crashed. It's happening after recording 10-15 times and CPU usage gradually increasing

Comment: I think this issue is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150961/ios7-webkit-crashes-frequently-not-freeing-up-memory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue related to the Code not iOS 7. Disposed unused media elements. Now it's working fine