# Sencha touch application being killed on iOS 7 due to memory pressure

Tags: ios, extjs, ios7, sencha-touch, touch

We have an application running on Touch 2.2.1 and are packaging it using Phonegap 2.2.

When running the application on an iOS device on an iPad 2 or iPad mini our application gets killed due to memory pressure. This does not occur on iPad 3's and up nor on an iPhone 5. It also does not occur when the devices have iOS 6 on them.

During troubleshooting we see that the VM: Garbage Collector in xCode is about 60-70% of the memory that the app is using.

Has anyone ran into issues that are similar or have any guidance on how to possible lower the memory footprint when the app goes into the background?

Appreciate any help.
Thanks,

Dan

Comment: I am having silimar problems, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150961/ios7-webkit-crashes-frequently-not-freeing-up-memory